# Merge 4 pdf's on one page while preserving size and adding trim marks

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I have four PDFs that are 8,7 x 12,65 cm. I want to place them 2 x 2 in an A4, which is 21 x 29,7 cm, so there is some space to have margin and preserve the original dimensions (*no up or down scaling!*): 3,6 cm vertically and 4,4 cm horizontally. Furthermore, I want to add small trim marks in between and in the margins to cut the 4 PDFs out once they are printed.

The outcome should look somewhat like this, where of course the trim marks are on the same line for a row and a column. **The PDF's themselves only contain the red rectangle, not yet the trim marks.** How can I achieve this, ideally in *Windows*?

[image]

Comment: You might need to merge the 4 PDFs into one, then print this PDF in 4-up. Printing in 4-up is not a problem, but merging 4 PDFs on consecutive pages requires finding a product that can do it.

Comment: @KJ Pdfcpu is a great tool, but I don't see an option that disallows rescaling when n-upping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I posted a link to a PDF you can use for the trim marks, but because the exact values you want are unknown until proven I have only done the last (top trim line because you can edit the PDF as text). More on that later, but to place the separate PDF pages we need an N-Up function and that needs a merge function before. So overall I suggested PDFcpu could be a cross platform open source solution.
We start with 4 single PDF page contents as 8.7 x 12.65 cm here is one of 4.
[image]

We merge into a single file using the 4 pages, fairly common programming procedure:-
[image]

Now for the N-Up
[image]
And finally the crop marks, However here we find PDFcpu cannot handle an incomplete PDF so need the template be fixed ONCE COMPLETE by any reader that can such as Acrobat Reader DC. Or any command line "PDF Fixer" such as Artifex GhostScript / MuTool or cpdf or qpdf as that is free open source too.
[image]

then water mark the cropping marks on the 4-UP.

```
pdfcpu.exe watermark add -m pdf -- "4rect.pdf" "sc:1.0 rel, rot:0"  4UP.pdf marked.pdf
writing marked.pdf...
```

Final result (but you need to decide and edit crop mark appearance)

[image]

And here is that incomplete registration template , where you can edit the red lines in MS notepad, similar to the last black line (split into 3 parts).

```
%PDF-1.2 
4 0 obj<<>>
stream 
% Let us quarter the page in grey
0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 1 J 1 w
298 000 m 298 842 l 000 421 m 596 421 l S

% For speed let us draw full length cut lines (we can recolour / tune / trim them easily later )
1 0 0 RG 1 J 1 w

% Verticals
% gap 26
026 000 m 026 842 l
% gap 246 = 8.678 mm
272 000 m 272 842 l
% gap 52
324 000 m 324 842 l
% gap 246 = 8.678 mm
570 000 m 570 842 l
% gap 26 and finally Stroke that colour group
S
% Horizontals
% gap 31
000 031 m 596 031 l
% gap 359 = 12.665 mm
000 390 m 596 390 l
% gap 62
000 452 m 596 452 l
% gap 359 = 12.665 mm
S
% Switch to black
0 0 0 RG 1 J 1 w
% gap 025 - 273 and 323 - 571 (alter to suit, you could even add SYMBOL txt)
000 811 m 025 811 l 273 811 m 323 811 l 571 811 m 596 811 l
S
endstream
endobj

3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox [0 0 596 842]/Parent 2 0 R/Contents 4 0 R/Resources <</Font<</F1<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Name/F1/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>>>>>>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj

xref
trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort you put in this answer! The only part that is very important for me, is the non-upscaling which is not preserved with 4NUP. However, it can be changed by changing `formsize:A4` to `dimensions:x y` where x and y are the size of one edge of a PDF in centimeters (times 2, because there has to be 2), multiplied by (72 / 2.54), because it's in 72 dpi and 1 inch is 2.54 cm. The only thing I don't know yet is how to resize this result to an A4 without zooming in the contents.

Comment: I found how to do it while also centering the contents. You need to install GhostScript and then run `gswin64 -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<</PageOffset [a b]>> setpagedevice" -f input.pdf`. Here is `a` equal to (595-x)/2 and `b` is (842-x)/2. 595 and 842 are dimensions of A4 in 72dpi, you divide by 2 to set the offset to half of the difference. And voilà! Now need to change the watermark accordingly.

Comment: You're right! It's uncanny because when I tried it when writing the above comments, I thought it was rescaled but it's not (kinda hard to check for me because there's a few cm of borders that are white in my actual pdfs). However when changing the dimensions in the command to the calculations in my first comment and n-upping, it strangely _does_ rescale, except when setting `margin:0`. But for the A4 formsize it's okay when inspecting further, so your answer makes total sense. Thank you so much for your help!